# laravel eloquent where and multiple or where

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using the Laravel Eloquent query builder and i want to have advance queries inside when clause

my eloquent :

```
bank::where('shop_id', $shopId)
            ->when(($search != ""), function ($query) use ($search) {
                return $query->orWhere('bank_name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                        ->orWhere('account_name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                        ->orWhere('account_number', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
            })->toSql();
```

sql from eloquent :

```
select * from bank 
where shop_id = 1 
and bank_name like '%Bank%' or 
account_name like '%Bank%' or 
account_number like '%Bank%'
```

sql result that i want:

```
select * from bank
where shop_id  = '1' 
and (bank_name like '%Bank%' or 
account_name like '%Bank%' or 
account_number like '%Bank%')
```

i can use subquery but its not efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the closure form of where around the or wheres:

```
bank::where('shop_id', $shopId)
    ->when(($search != ""), function ($query) use ($search) {
        return $query->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            return $query
                ->orWhere('bank_name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('account_name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('account_number', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        })
    })
    ->toSql();
```